# How can I use a CredentialPicker with AuthenticationProtocol.Custom?

Tags: windows-8

How can I use a `CredentialPicker` with `AuthenticationProtocol` set to `Custom`?

To do this, I need to set `CustomAuthenticationProtocol` to something to avoid an `ArgumentException`. However, if I set it to a value other than one of the predefined values, I receive the following exception:

> A specified authentication package is unknown. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070554)